# Encode password using php shall and decode it in cookie

Tags: php, cookies, salt

I want to remember username and password.
When check cookie will set and hash the password but when retuning the hashed password in password field it also show hashed vale
here is my code to encode and decode please can someone give a better solution?

```
I use this to remember password
<?php
if($_POST['remember']) {
$remember_user = trim($_POST['username']);
$remember_pass = trim($_POST['password']);

$salt = "@g26jQsG&nh*&#8v";
$password_hash =  sha1($remember_pass.$salt);

setcookie('remember_user', $remember_user, $year);
setcookie('remember_pass', $password_hash, $year);


                $cookie_name = 'siteAuth';
        $cookie_time = time() - 100;
       $password_hash =  sha1($remember_pass.$salt);
   setcookie ($cookie_name, 'usr='.$remember_user.'&hash='.$password_hash, time() + $cookie_time);



}
else if(!$_POST['remember']) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_user']) && parse_str($_COOKIE['remember_pass'])) {

    if(($usr == $remember_user) && ($hash == md5($remember_pass)))
        {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $remember_user;
        }

                $cookie_name = 'siteAuth';
                $cookie_time = time() - 100;
                  setcookie ($cookie_name, 'usr='.$remember_user.'&hash='.$password_hash, time() + $cookie_time);

    }


}
?>
```

Here is my html part that i want to display the remembered password

```
      <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="text" autocomplete="on" value="<?php    
  $salt="@g26jQsG&nh*&#8v"; 
  $password = sha1($_COOKIE['remember_pass'].$salt); echo $password; ?>"/>
```

But still am getting this in output `f58b28222887e5cd4d10ec75d4bf2617c13a3f4a`
I want to return the original password 
how can i do that?

Comment: you cannot decode sha 256

Comment: No other method to archive this? @яша

Comment: Never send the password to the client

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

See: http://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you want to authenticate,Either you or anybody else should never know the client's password! never means never !

if you wish to Authenticate you should always follow this procedure :

Client Register : `hash(password+salt)` =>insert to DB
Client Authentication : you check if

```
hash(Input_Password+salt)==(Password in DB)
```